# Changing pictures by clicking on a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text on a list

```
<ul class="1">
  <li class="liHEADER">ANIMALS</li>
    <li class="animalss">LION</li>
    <li class="animalss">TIGER</li>
    <li class="animalss">CHEETAH</li>
</ul>
```

and I have a `<div>` for the pictures and the labels

```
<div class="show">   
  <div class="pic"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
  <div class="labels">LION</div>

  <div class="pic"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
  <div class="labels">TIGER</div>

  <div class="pic"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
  <div class="labels">CHEETAH</div>
</div>
```

what I was intending to do is when I click on the word `LION` the `<div>` will show the picture of the lion and its label and then, when clicked on the `tiger` the lion pic and label will be hidden and the tiger will be shown...any javascript or jquery command for this?

I'm sorry I just not very good at this.

Comment: Look at .contains and .on("click" ... You may make your life easier by wrapping each image and caption in a div with ID that matches the word

Comment: you can use jquery ui fadeIn() and fadeout() could help you a lot but still you need to work on it  here is a  simple exampl: http://www.w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=jquery_effect_fadeout_fadein. and you could check jquery office website to see how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution :)

[Js Fiddler Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/krWu8/12/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="1">
  <li class="liHEADER">ANIMALS</li>
   <li class="animalss">LION</li>
   <li class="animalss">TIGER</li>
   <li class="animalss">CHEETAH</li>
</ul>

    <div class="show">   
    <div class="pic" data-name="lion"><img  src="http://rs183.pbsrc.com/albums/x46/rebelrhoads/Lion.jpg~c200"/></div>
 <div class="labels" data-name="lion">LION</div>

 <div class="pic" data-name="tiger"><img src="http://www.perthzoo.wa.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Sumatran-Tiger.jpg"/></div>
 <div class="labels" data-name="tiger">TIGER</div>

 <div class="pic" data-name="cheetah"><img src="http://blog.londolozi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/thumb-cheetah.jpg"/></div>
 <div class="labels" data-name="cheetah">CHEETAH</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
li{
color:#999;
cursor:pointer;
 }
  li.selected{
  color:#000;
 }
li:hover{
color:#000;
}

div.pic, div.labels{
display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
        $('li').click(showAnimal);
});

function showAnimal(){
        $('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var animal = $(this).text();

        if(animal.toString().toLowerCase() == "animals")
            $('div[data-name]').show();
        else{
            $('div.pic').hide();
            $('div.labels').hide();

            $('div[data-name=' + animal.toString().toLowerCase() + ']').show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea:

html

```
<div class="show">   
  <div class="pic lion"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
  <div class="labels lion">LION</div>

  <div class="pic tiger"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
  <div class="labels tiger">TIGER</div>

  <div class="pic cheetah"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
  <div class="labels cheetah">CHEETAH</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
 $(function(){
    $('.animalss').click(function(){
      switch($(this).text()){
        case 'LION': 
           $('.pic').not('.lion').hide();
           $('.labels').not('.lion').hide();
           $('.lion').show();
        break;
        case 'TIGER': 
           $('.pic').not('.tiger').hide();
           $('.labels').not('.tiger').hide();
           $('.tiger').show();
        break;
       case 'CHEETAH': 
           $('.pic').not('.cheetah').hide();
           $('.labels').not('.cheetah').hide();
           $('.cheetah').show();
        break;
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<label>ANIMALS</label>
<ul class="1">
    <li class="animalss">LION</li>
    <li class="animalss">TIGER</li>
    <li class="animalss">CHEETAH</li>
</ul>

<div class="show">
 <div class="lion" style="display:none">   
   <div class="pic"><img src="LION.jpg"></div>
  <div class="labels">LION</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tiger" style="display:none">  
  <div class="pic"><img src="LION.jpg"></div>
  <div class="labels">TIGER</div>
</div>
<div class="cheetah" style="display:none">  
  <div class="pic"><img src="LION.jpg"></div>
  <div class="labels">CHEETAH</div>
</div>      
</div>
```

Jquery Script

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
   var text=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
   $('.'+text).show('slow').siblings().hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fLZHq/6/)

Comment: But in this case you are linking the text of the list element to a variable what about if you want to write something like the BLACK LION as a label that would make two classes instead of just one :S ...

Answer (score 0):

//check the solution on fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ks5n/)
http://jsfiddle.net/5Ks5n/

html

```
<ul class="animal-list">
    <li class="liHEADER" data-view="lion">Lion</li>
    <li class="animalss" data-view="tiger">Tiger</li>
</ul>

<div class="show">   
      <div class="pic" style="display:none" data-animal="lion">
          <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OiigZsVwwNQ/UFM5KDugeiI/AAAAAAAAJ_Y/HrPEPFnSXCI/s1600/Male+Lion+Wallpapers+1.jpg" />
      <div class="labels">LION</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pic" style="display:none" data-animal="tiger">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OiigZsVwwNQ/UFM5KDugeiI/AAAAAAAAJ_Y/HrPEPFnSXCI/s1600/Male+Lion+Wallpapers+1.jpg" />
        <div class="labels">TIGER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on("click",".animal-list",function(element){
    var $target = $(element.target);
    var animal = $target.attr("data-view");
    $(".pic").hide();
    $("[data-animal='"+ animal +"']").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
  <label>ANIMALS</label>
  <ul class="1">
    <li class="animalss">LION</li>
    <li class="animalss">TIGER</li>
    <li class="animalss">CHEETAH</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="show">
    <div class="lion_pic" style="display:none">
      <img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
      <label>LION</label>
    </div>
    <div class="tiger_pic" style="display:none">
      <img src="TIGER.jpg"></pic>
      <label>TIGER</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cheetah_pic" style="display:none">
      <img src="CHEETAH.jpg"></pic>
      <label>CHEETAH</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS Code:

```
  $('ul.1').click(function(e){
    var type = $(e.target).text();
    if(type === 'LION'){
      $('.lion_pic').show();
      $('.tiger_pic').hide();
      $('.cheetah_pic').hide();
    } else if(type === 'TIGER'){
      $('.tiger_pic').show();
      $('.lion_pic').hide()
      $('.cheetah_pic').hide()
    } else {
      $('.cheetah_pic').show();
      $('.lion_pic').hide()
      $('.tiger_pic').hide()
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest but not shortest way to do this to assign classes to a group, group mean elements wich are interact with each oter i.e. lion text, image and lable in your case. Then use this code:

```
 <pre>
<style>
.show div{display:none;}
</style>
    <ul class="1">
      <li class="liHEADER">ANIMALS</li>
        <li class="animalss" id = "lion" onclick="showImage(this.id);">LION</li>
        <li class="animalss" id = "tiger" onclick="showImage(this.id);">TIGER</li>
        <li class="animalss" id="cheetah" onclick="showImage(this.id);">CHEETAH</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="show">   
      <div class="pic lion"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
      <div class="labels lion">LION</div>

      <div class="pic tiger"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
      <div class="labels tiger">TIGER</div>

      <div class="pic cheetah"><img src="LION.jpg"></pic>
      <div class="labels cheetah">CHEETAH</div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Then jQuery will be

```
<pre>
<script>
function showImage(param){
  var classToShow = param;
  $('.'+param).show();
  $('.show div:not("."'+param+'")').hide();
}
</script>
</pre>
```

Check for syntex error and let me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have reformatted your HTML so that its much easier to illustrate since I think maybe you are able to change the HTML of your site.  This is perhaps how most people write code for  [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

```
<ul>
    <li class="animals"><a href="#lion">LION</a></li>
    <li class="animals"><a href="#tiger">TIGER</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content">   
    <div class="pic" id="lion">
        <img src="LION.jpg" />
        <div class="labels">LION</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic" id="tiger">
        <img src="TIGER.jpg" />
        <div class="labels">TIGER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jQuery code,

```
$(".pic").hide();
$("a[href='#lion']").on('click', function() {
    $(".pic").hide();
    $("#lion").show();    
});
$("a[href='#tiger']").on('click', function() {
    $(".pic").hide();
    $("#tiger").show();    
});
```

everytime we reload the page, we make sure the  are hidden using $(".pic").hide().  Then when the user clicks LION or TIGER links, we will hide both and then show only the correct div, which is either LION or TIGER.  Here is a [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/quik_silv/C3ZAY/).  It is certainly possible to make the code even shorter by abstracting LION and TIGER to ANIMALS (or well, anything you want), but then it will be harder to understand for beginners.